# data restructuring offset 3 year rolling window new columns pandas

Tags: pandas

a little new to data manipulation and might be a tough question to follow so bear with me, please.

I have this dataframe in pandas (apologies for the sketchy creation of a dataframe with transpose - sure there's a more efficient way):

```
f2 = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(np.array([[10,30,50,11,21],[2006,2007,2008,2009,2010]]),
           index=['one','date'],columns=[1,2,3,4,5]))
```

and what I'm trying to do is create new columns in the data frame that offset the variables in column 'one' both -1 year and + 1 year, creating a 3 year rolling window of data. For instance, taking the year 2007 for example, I aim to create columns with the variables one_-1year (2006), one_0year (2007), and one_0year (2008). The end data frame would be to remove the variables for 2006 and 2010 as they don't have a 3-year rolling window worth of data.

Difficult question to follow, i presume. but the end dataframe i am seeking is this:

```
f3 = np.transpose(pd.DataFrame(np.array([[10,30,50],[30,50,11],[50,11,21],[2007,2008,2009]]),
           index=['one_-1year', 'one_-0year','one_1year','date'],columns=[1,2,3]))
```

where two new columns were created '-1 year' and '+1 year'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your specific starting and ending examples, you can create the "-1year" and "1year" columns using `.shift()`, then drop rows with missing data introduced by `shift`ing at the start and end, and finally rename and rearrange columns:

```
df = f2.copy()
df['one_-1year'] = df['one'].shift()
df['one_1year'] = df['one'].shift(-1)
df = df.rename(columns={'one': 'one_-0year'})
df = df[['one_-1year', 'one_-0year', 'one_1year', 'date']].dropna()
```

Result:

|  | one_-1year | one_-0year | one_1year | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 | 30 | 50 | 2007 |
| 3 | 30 | 50 | 11 | 2008 |
| 4 | 50 | 11 | 21 | 2009 |

Comment: ah, the shift() is what i was looking for -- thank you!